# The sent gmail was modified to other version, how to trace the record beside header?

Tags: gmail, header

Recently, the emails I sent from gmail were either modified or the documents got replaced for others.

When i communicated with google, they only asked for the header but nothing else ..

Also, when i see the devices in recent activities, I see a WINDOWS PHONE which is not my device, but google has only advised me to change the password.

But this has happened many times already.

What should i do?

Comment: Have you checked latest activity? https://support.google.com/mail/answer/45938?hl=en What do you see there? Check IP addresses: are they yours?

Answer (score 1):

> the emails I sent from gmail were either modified or the documents got
>   replaced for others

Where do you see the modification? In general, email does not guarantee the integrity of the messages, you need to [digitally sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) them to have this feature.

If you see the modifications on your Google account then someone has signed in with your credentials or used your device.

If you see the modification at the receiving end than either the receiveing end has modified the content or someone on the way (not likely).

> Also, when i see the devices in recent activities, I see a WINDOWS
>   PHONE which is not my device, but google has only advised me to change
>   the password.

Changing the password is not enough if the new password leaks somehow (for instance via a keylogger or someone spying at you). You need to enable [multifactor authentication](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/). In that scenario, someone having your login and password will not be able to log in **from a new device** - they will be required to also provide a number which changes every minute.